# Generic interface property type based off of passed in type property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic interface that has a field that is based off of the passed in type.

I'm wondering if it's possible to then have another field be of any type of the passed in type

for example:

```
interface sampleObject {
   name: fullName
   age: number
   address: string
}

interface fullName{
   first: string
   middle: string
   last: string
}

// imagine I pass in type sampleObject

interface genericType<T, Key = keyof T> {
  field: Key // valid values are "name" | "age" | "address"
  fieldTypes: ??? // I want the valid types to be fullName | number | string
}
```

I've tried using `fieldTypes: T[keyof T]` and this almost gets me what I want but it says the type is `fullName | number | string | undefined`, which then throws error ts(2322).

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the right way or not.

Comment: May I ask what's the end goal of having an array of the possible types? And what kind of errors did you get with what you tried?

Comment: In my testing, your solution (using `T[keyof T]` ) worked perfectly. It did properly accept objects constructed with "fieldTypes" values that are of type number, string, etc and did properly reject others (undefined, number[], etc).  Perhaps you could share a full example that demonstrates how `T[keyof T]` does not work for you?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre]; I can't reproduce the issue you're talking about; I don't see `undefined`. Instead of asking us to "imagine" you pass in a type, please make the example do it, so that when we paste it into our own IDEs we see what you're seeing.  Also, please consider using conventional namings. Custom types are conventionally written in UpperCamelCase and not lowerCamelCase; switching those makes types look like variables, which is distracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this could be useful:

```
type KVPairs<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = 
K extends keyof T
    ? { field: K, fieldTypes: T[K] } 
    : never;
    
type genericType<T> = KVPairs<T>;
```